# runtimeerror missing handler python glade

Tags: python, glade

This is a piece of my code

```
class gui_manage():
    def delete_event(self , widget , data):
        False
        print 'delete'
    # #######################
    # define some functions here
     as example : start_download(self ,widget)
    ########################################
    def start_download( self , widget  ):
        print 'add_url_clicked'

    def __init__(self):
        builder = gtk.Builder()
        builder.add_from_file('gui.glade')
        win=builder.get_object('add_url_win')
        text_entry= builder.get_object('url_entry')
        signals ={ 
         'delete_event' : self.delete_event , 
         'destroy' : self.destroy  ,
         'cancel_button_clicked' : self.delete_event , 
         'addpaused_button_clicked' : self.addpaused ,
     'start_download_clicked' : self.start_download , 
         'addpaused_button_clicked' : self.addpaused 
         }
        builder.connect_signals(signals)
```

the glade file shows the corresponding lines:

```xml
<object class="GtkButton" id="start_download">
    <property name="label" translatable="yes">start download</property>
      <property name="visible">True</property>
           <property name="can_focus">True</property>
           <property name="receives_default">True</property>
      <property name="tooltip_text" translatable="yes">start download now ...</property>
    <property name="use_action_appearance">False</property>
<signal name="clicked" handler="start_download" swapped="no"/>'
```

I got the error :

```
gui_manage.py:45: RuntimeWarning: missing handler 'start_download'
  builder.connect_signals(signals)
```

however the `delete_event()` method called by clicked ' event of the cancel button ' successfully.

In brief, all methods defined by the same way, connected in the same dictionary, although some is missing!

Comment: is it clear???
/n I call many methods , some of them missed , & the other called normally !!

Answer (score 0):

It work good now :

```
'def start_download( self , object  ):
    print 'add_url_clicked''
```

instead of

```
'def start_download( self , widget  ):
    print 'add_url_clicked''
```

&

```
'self.signals = {}'
```

instead of

```
'signals = {}'
```

&

```
'self.builder.connect_signals(self)'
```

instead of

```
'self.builder.connect_signals(signals)'
```

thancks for all